# Why does Eclipse-CDT say self-assignment is an error?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, googletest

I was doing unit test in eclipse g++ using google test. I got an error when i tried to unit test the self assignment check in the class i designed.

as usual, the overload is pretty standard and looks like this:

```
CLASS operator=(const CLASS& rhs);
```

and when i tried to have this in the test:

```
CLASS A;
A = A;   //compile error here, saying self assignment to itself. have no clue why, though.
```

I wonder if there is a specific way for self assignment test. Thanks.

FYI, below is the snapshot of the error

[image]

Comment: _'An error would come up'_ Could you elaborate on this in particular, as usual here please! It's actually quite unclear what you're asking about. Also the many tags you gave may unnecessarily narrow the audience taking notice to give appropriate answers for your question.

Comment: already put everything i had in the question, though  @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: _'saying self assignment to itself'_ Isn't any compiler error message I have ever seen! Also you seemingly got my hints about the tagging wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  neither have i, and thats why i turned to this site for help.

Comment: Does the CLASS have any pointers that require deep copying ?

Comment: Show a screenshot then please (I'm asking for such rarely, but in this case it might make sense). If you say 'compile error' please post the message here literally. If it's not an english message, at least use a translator to show it in your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   check out the update..

Comment: Is your class derived from any other class? What other methods does your class provide? How is your `operator=` implemented?

Comment: @Svalorzen   for operator=, it would check self assignment first. 
if(this == &rhs)  return *this; Otherwise, just do a one by one copy of every member variable inside the class. all double type.

Comment: @Svalorzen  it's not derived from another class.

Comment: Can you show the class?

Comment: I'm completely not sure about it, but could it be that Eclipse is trying to prevent errors for you? This link reports features very similar to what you are experiencing: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-codan/

Comment: @Veritas there are only default constructor and this operator=. All the member variables are all double. that's it. no other fancy or complex stuff

Comment: @Svalorzen  how to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, I have no clue. The link does show a settings page where you can configure those things. I think you have to find that and figure things out for yourself.

Comment: @Svalorzen in fact, self assignment checking is good. however, over here it is not supposed to be an error. i wonder if some set-up is available for my specific requirement.

Comment: `CLASS operator=(const CLASS& rhs);` is not "pretty standard"; it should return `CLASS &`.  If your copy-constructor works by delegating to `operator=` (it shouldn't but people sometimes do that) then you're in for some pain.

Comment: Voted to reopen. There is sufficient information to diagnose the problem with high probability, per my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A self assignment statement `x = x`; is not, of course, an error in C++
and you do not have any *compiler* error here.

If you run a build of your project and look at the output in the IDE **Console**
tab, rather than the **Problems** tab, you will see that the compiler does
not report such an error. Unless it *does* report some error, you project will build
successfully.

If you look at the self-assignment error reported under the **Problems**
tab you will see that its **Type** is **Code Analysis Problem**, not **C/C++ Problem**.
This means that the problem is reported by the Eclipse CDT Code Analyser
(Codan), not by the compiler.

Codan is reporting self-assignment as an error because self-assignment is
almost always a *programming mistake*. But in your case it is deliberate.

You have two choices:

- 1). Ignore the Code Analysis error
- 2). Change the Code Analysis settings of the project so that this error is
  not reported.

To do 2):

- Navigate **Properties** -> **C/C++ General** -> **Code Analysis**
- Enable **Use project settings**
- Either:-

  - Disable problem **Assignment to itself**, or
  - Select **Assignment to itself**, then navigate **Customize Selected...** -> **Preferences**
    and change the problem's severity from *Error* to *Warning* or *Info*.
- OK out of project **Properties**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if it is possible to have self assignment checked on while not getting the error at that step. the reason is because self assigning is great and i dont wanna lose this capacity.

Comment: @STNYU Yes it is. Re-read the answer and note how to convert the Codan error into a *warning* or *info* diagnostic. And to repeat the main point: No matter what Codan says, the compiler will still compile self-assignments for you.

Comment: another option is to add a `// @suppress ("Assignment to itself")` and a comment why you would to tha in this case, this way the IDE will not complain and your future self might be glad you explained that part of the code